# Error while implementing using in powershell

Tags: powershell, using

Following [this](http://www.sbrickey.com/Tech/Blog/Post/IDisposable_in_PowerShell) post when I am trying to implement Using functionality in Powershell

```
Function cUsing {
    param (
        [System.IDisposable] $inputObject = $(throw "The parameter -inputObject is required."),
        [ScriptBlock] $scriptBlock = $(throw "The parameter -scriptBlock is required.")
    )
    Try { &$scriptBlock }
    Finally {
        if ($inputObject -ne $null) {
            if ($inputObject.psbase -eq $null) {
                $inputObject.Dispose()
            } else {
                $inputObject.psbase.Dispose()
            }
        }
    }
}


    cUsing($sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)
{
$sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=myserver; Database=master; Integrated Security= True"
$sqlConnection.Open()
$sqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT STATEMENT"
$sqlCmd.Connection = $sqlConnection
$dsValues = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$daValues = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($sqlCmd)
$daValues.Fill($dsValues)
Write-Host $dsValues.Tables[0]
}
```

Error:

```
[ScriptBlock] $scriptBlock = $(throw  <<<< "The parameter -scriptBlock is required.")
```

**Edit [Graimer]**

When I have moved the curly braces like below

```
cUsing($sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection){
....
....
 Write-Host $dsValues.Tables[0]}
```

I am not getting any error but the output which I am getting is

```
    $sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=myserver; Database=master; Integrated Security= True"
$sqlConnection.Open()
$sqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$sqlCmd.CommandText = "Select query"
$sqlCmd.Connection = $sqlConnection
$dsValues = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$daValues = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($sqlCmd)
$daValues.Fill($dsValues)
Write-Host $dsValues.Tables[0]
```

**EDIT [Ansgar Wiechers]**

when I have changed the scriptblock line to

```
Function cUsing {
param (
    [System.IDisposable] $inputObject = $(throw "The parameter -inputObject is required."),
    [ScriptBlock] $scriptBlock = ${throw "The parameter -scriptBlock is required."}
)
```

I am not getting any error but I am getting the same output which I have showed in **Edit** above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you don't provide the scriptblock as a parameter, but as a command on it's own. Commands in Powershell are on a single line. Your code runs the command with only the using parameter, and fails. THEN you declare a scriptblock.

You have two options here; escape the linebreak(BAD practice), or move the opening curly brace one line up so it is considered part of the `cusing` command. Like this:

```
cUsing($sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection) {
    $sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=myserver; Database=master; Integrated Security= True"
...
..
.
}
```

Comment: When I have moved the curly brackets in above line (*cUsing($sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection){* I am not getting any error but now it is not giving me correct result. It is just displaying me what is written inside curly braces.

Comment: Are you using PS1.0 ? The code runs flawless in PS2.0 and PS3.0. Btw, you should call PS functions like `cUsing ($sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection) {` . Notice that space is used to seperate functionname from paramterer and the parameters from eachother.

Comment: I have get-host and the version I got is 2.0

Comment: How aree you running the script? are you calling a script-file(untitled1.ps1) or using the play button in PS ISE? Because ISE prints the commands it runs in the console, are you sure that's not it? Also, `Write-Host` is for outputting messages to the console, not outputing the result(so you can store it). Replace `Write-Host $dsValues.Tables[0]` with `$dsValues.Tables[0]` in the end. Then save the file as a script and call it from a new powershell console using something like `.\untitled1.ps1` . Do you get the data?

Comment: I am running it on PowerGui. I am still wondering why is showing me that output. May be because everything after *cUsing* is being considered as string and that's why I am getting all that code as a string. Just a thought !

Comment: Pleide perform the steps I suggested in the previous comment. Replacing the last line and running the script in a real powershell window. since I can't reproduce your issue you need to perform these tasks.

Comment: After some try it is working now.. without any error but when I am using this statement outside using *$sqlConnection.Close()* I am not getting any error. Does it mean that my object didn't die ?

Comment: you can call dispose multiple times without any error. I believe close works similar.

Answer (score 0):

A script block is defined via curly braces, not via `$()`. Like this:

```
[ScriptBlock]$scriptBlock = { throw "The parameter ..." }
```

`$()` is the operator for evaluating subexpressions.

Comment: That did resolve the error but I am not getting any output from the query now. Am I missing something? I have edited my question with the result.

Comment: `{ ... }`, not `${ ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Add-Type @"
        using System;

        public class Code : System.IDisposable
        {
            public bool IsDisposed { get; set; }
            public void Dispose() 
            {
                Dispose(true);
                GC.SuppressFinalize(this);      
            }

            protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
            {
                if (!IsDisposed)
                {
                    IsDisposed = true;   
                }
            }
        }
    "@

    function using-block {
        param (
            [System.IDisposable]$InputObject = $(throw "The parameter -inputObject is required."),
            [ScriptBlock]$ScriptBlock = $(throw "The parameter -scriptBlock is required.")
        )
        try { &$ScriptBlock }
        finally {
            if ($InputObject) {
                if ($InputObject.PSBase) {
                    $InputObject.PSBase.Dispose()
                } else {
                    $InputObject.Dispose()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    using-block($c = New-Object Code) {
        $c.IsDisposed
    }
    $c.IsDisposed
```

Outputs:

False

True

Comment: When I am running the same above code in a separate window I am getting below error *$c.IsDisposed <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (        using S...  $c.IsDisposed:String) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString* I am running this on **PowerGUI**. Am I missing anything?